# Lower bound of the length of a sum of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

Let $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $y=\Sigma^k_{i=1}x_i’$, where $x_i’$ denotes $x_i$ or $-x_i$. Does there always exist an appropriate choice of plus or minus for each $x_i’$ such that $\sqrt{n}|y|\geq \Sigma^k_{i=1}|x_i|$? (Here $|\cdot|$ stands for the common Euclidean norm.)

Comment: Hint: If you show that $\Bbb E x_j\cdot x_k=0$ for $j\ne k$ it follows that $\Bbb E|y|^2=\sum|x_j|^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon \in \{0,1\}^k$ (such that $x_i'=  \epsilon_i x_i$).
Then, we have :
\begin{align*}
\left\| \sum_{i=1}^k \epsilon_i x_i \right\|^2 &= \sum_{i=1}^n \|x_i\|^2 + 2 \sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i \left\langle x_i, \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} \epsilon_jx_j \right\rangle
\end{align*}

We can choose the $(\epsilon_i)$ inductively such that :
$$\forall i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}, \epsilon_i \left\langle x_i, \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} \epsilon_jx_j \right\rangle \geq 0$$

Then, we have :
$$\left\| \sum_{i=1}^k \epsilon_i x_i \right\|^2 \geq \sum_{i=1}^n \|x_i\|^2$$
and therefore
$$\sqrt n\left\| \sum_{i=1}^k \epsilon_i x_i \right\|\geq \sum_{i=1}^n \|x_i\|$$